# Trying to set a list of hashtags in my tags table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hashtag

Let's say a user inputs -> #ruby #rails #flight 
I'm trying to split the list of hashtags and set it in my tags table provided the tag isn't already in the table.

```
def tag_list=(names)
    self.tags = names.split("#").map do |n|
      Tag.where(name: n.strip).first_or_create!
    end
end
```

Problem is it's setting an empty value as the first tag.
How do i make all the hashtags lowercase and also how do i make it ignore space so #cake#bake works just as well as #cake #bake.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

power of the regexp, to the rescue ! (cue heroic pose)

```
>> "#ruby #rail­s #flig­ht".scan /#([^­#\s]+)/
=>  [["ruby"],["rails"],["flight"]]
```

more seriously :

- `String#scan` finds all matches of a regexp in the string, and returns an array
- inside the regexp, we have :

  - match the # character,
  - open a capture group (that's why we have an array of arrays),
  - match one or more characters that are neither a # nor whitespace,
  - close capture group.

a simpler version can be : `/#(\w+)/`, where the matched characters are only "word" characters.

To make all the characters lowercase, just do:

```
"#ruby #rail­s #flig­ht".scan( /#(\w+)/ ).flatten.map( &:downcase )
```

Comment: Damn! I seriously need to learn this regex thing. Thanks! i'll try it out now.

Comment: added precisions, the output must be flattened because capture groups produce arrays. If you want to practice regexps, I recommend [rubular](http://rubular.com/) to get hands-on, and obviously, read the [Regexp API page](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html).

Comment: Worked as a dream. Thanksss!

Comment: Thanks for the links as well, need to up my game on regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
names.strip.split("#").compact.each do |tag|
  tags << Tag.where(name: tag).first_or_create!
end
```